# SQL Access - SELECT TOP (variable)

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I am new in SQL - Access. I am trying to make SQL in Access that show me in my query data base on Month (date from form). For example if in form is (15.05.2017) I want to show data from 01/2017 to 05/2017 as shown bellow. For this I used "SELECT TOP 5", but I need it to be variable. Many thanks :)

[SELECT TOP 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhBFJ.png)

Comment: you could use a WHERE clause with your desired dates in rather than using TOP. And then you can make those variable much more easily

Comment: You can create the query string using VBA.

Answer (score 1):

The TOP number cannot be parameterized. Use the year from the date in the form and filter only records from that year, also use the month from the date in the form and filter only records with a month less than or equal to that month.